# VB.Net - how to create a dictionary of variant types?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

In VB6 it was possible to define a dictionary object, (By a reference to the scripting library). In python there's no limitation on the types of values (and very few restrictions on key types).

What is the VB.NET (visual basic.net) way to have a dictionary of variant types?

e.g.

```
d(key1) = "text"
d(key2) = 53
d(key3) = 3.1415
d(key4) = {array...}
```

?

Comment: You can use a [`HashTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) or (better) a `Dictionary(Of Object, Object)`. But i would avoid a loosely typed collection like this since it is slow and error-prone. What are you actually trying to do? Maybe you need to create an interface an let your objects implement it.

Comment: To add to Tim's comment (which is really an answer), Object is the catch-all type in VB.NET.  Use it in place of the old VB6 Variant data type in most cases.

Comment: dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)   works.  To complete tim's answer, an import is needed: Imports System.Collections.Generic

Comment: Did you not want to answer Tim's question? The reason he didn't post his comment as an answer was because he was hoping he could get you to provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish so we could suggest an *even better* way. `Dictionary(Of Object, Object)` will certainly work, but it's a code smell. There's almost undoubtedly a better way to solve your problem.